# Analytics Tracking Solely in Controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, google-analytics

I have a Laravel application that is heavily dependent upon AJAX calls. I want to track application activity using Google Analytics. I am looking at an [analytics tracking package](https://packagist.org/packages/ipunkt/laravel-analytics) where I can track application activity in the controller. I am thinking that I can track all activity solely through the controller and not bother with placing tracking code in templates or elsewhere.

Questions:
Is my understanding correct that I will not be missing anything by solely using the controller for analytics tracking? 
Are there any big 'gotchas' that I should be considering?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only track activity from the server you'll miss things like screen size/resolution and browser/OS data (unless you override the User Agent). You also won't be able to do things like track events, exception, or social interaction. Essentially, any interaction that is only available to the client is something you will not be able to track.

These things may not matter to you, but you should be aware of them before making the switch.